# Pygame のコードでエラー: ‘int’ object has no attribute ‘rect’

Tags: python, pygame

当たり判定のコードを書きたいです。

playerを十字キーで操作して、動いてやってくるen1に当たったら、playerが初期位置に戻るプログラムです。

「player とen1が当たったら」としたいのですが、以下の箇所でエラーが出ます。
どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

**該当箇所:**

```
if self.rect.colliderect(self.en1.rect):
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
‘int’ object has no attribute ‘rect’
```

初心者で、見よう見まねでやっているので、無駄な点が多いとは思いますが、どうかよろしくお願いします。

参考にしたページ:
https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/pygame-blockout/

**現状のコード:**

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
pygame.mixer
import random

SCREEN = Rect(1500, 800, 0, 32)

#雲
class ClSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, filename, x, y, vx, vy):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.containers)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = [x, y]
    self.vx = vx
    self.vy = vy
    w = self.image.get_width()
def update(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(self.vx, self.vy)
    if self.rect.right < 0:
        self.rect.left = 1500
   
#Player
class PlayerSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, filename, en1, x, y, vx, vy, angle=0):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.containers)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = [x, y]
    self.vx = vx
    self.vy = vy
    self.angle = angle
    if angle != 0: self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
    self.jump = pygame.mixer.Sound("j2.mp3")
    self.deth = pygame.mixer.Sound("aa.wav")
    w = self.image.get_width()
    h = self.image.get_height()
    self.rect = Rect(x, y, w, h)   
    self.en1 = en1

def Rmove(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(30, 0)
def Lmove(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(-30, 0)
def Umove(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(0, -70)
def update(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(self.vx, self.vy)
    if self.rect.left < 0 :
       self.rect.left = 0
    if self.rect.top < 0 :
       self.rect.top = 0
    if self.rect.top > 810 :
       self.de()
    if self.rect.top > 930 :
       pygame.quit()
       sys.exit()
       
    if self.rect.colliderect(self.en1.rect):
     self.rect.left = 0 
def de(self):
    self.deth.play(1)
def bjump(self):
    self.jump.play(1)    

#En1
class En1Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, filename, xy, vxy, angle=0):
    x, y = xy
    vx, vy = vxy
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,self.containers)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    w = self.image.get_width()
    h = self.image.get_height()
    self.rect = Rect(x, y, w, h)
    self.vx = vx
    self.vy = vy
    self.angle = angle
    if angle != 0: self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)

def update(self):
    self.rect.move_ip(self.vx, self.vy)
    if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > 850:
       self.vy = -self.vy

def main():
    pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 801), 0, 32)
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
pygame.display.set_caption("Test") 

bg = pygame.image.load("img.jpg").convert_alpha()
rect_bg = bg.get_rect()

   #supurite group
    group = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()
en1 = pygame.sprite.Group() 

En1Sprite.containers = group, en1
PlayerSprite.containers = group
ClSprite.containers = group

    #sprite
    s = -10
for m in range(7):
    m = random.randint(0, 800)
    for n in range(300):
     n = random.randint(200, 1000000)
     en1 = En1Sprite("to.PNG", (n, m), (s, 3), 0)
en1 = En1Sprite("to.PNG", (4400, 0), (-4,3), 0)

player = PlayerSprite("m.png", 0, 600, 0, 5, 0)

cloud = ClSprite("clo.png", 700, 600, s, 0)
cloud = ClSprite("clo.png", 900, 100, s, 0)
cloud = ClSprite("clo.png", 300, 500, s, 0)
cloud = ClSprite("clo.png", 100, 300, s, 0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while (1):
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.fill((0, 100, 0, 0)) 
    screen.blit(bg, rect_bg) 
    group.update()
    group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()  

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==  pygame.KEYDOWN: 
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
             player.Lmove()
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
             player.Rmove()
           if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
             player.Umove()
             player.bjump()
          
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()          
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: 質問の際にインデントが全て無くなってどのようなプログラムだか分からなくなっています。ソースコード部分を編集して調査・検証可能なように修正してください。また、参考にした書籍や記事とか、どのような動作をするプログラムかと言った情報も出来るだけ追記するようにしてください。

Comment: すみません、編集しました。何か問題等あればまたよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考にしたページのソースコードと比べると、質問記事のソースコードは未だほとんどのインデントがずれていたり色々と不完全でまともに動作しないレベルだと思われます。質問記事に表示された状態と実際のソースコードが合っているかを再度確認してみてください。質問で発生している現象とソースコードが合っていないように見えます。それが合っているなら大部分のインデントを間違えているようですので、参考にしたページのソースコードを参考に、正しいインデントになるように整えてみてください。あと4行目の`pygame.mixer`の頭に`import`が抜けています。

Answer (score 0):

質問のソースコードが正しく修正され、問題を再現できるようになったという前提で考えると、原因は以下になるでしょう。
(引用しているソースコードは全て現時点でのインデント等が正しくないと思われるソースコードです)

以下の行で`PlayerSprite`の初期化パラメータの2つ目が [pygame.Rect](http://westplain.sakuraweb.com/translate/pygame/Rect.cgi) を含むオブジェクト(おそらく`class En1Sprite`のインスタンス)ではなく、単なる整数の`0`が指定されているために発生していると思われます。

```
player = PlayerSprite("m.png", 0, 600, 0, 5, 0)
```

PlayerSpriteクラスの関連するソースは以下のようになっており、初期化で整数の`0`が指定されていた`en1`をそのまま代入して、`update()`の中で`en1`に`rect`という変数があることを前提に処理が行われています。

```
#Player
class PlayerSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, filename, en1, x, y, vx, vy, angle=0):
                  ...途中省略...
    self.en1 = en1
                  ...途中省略...
def update(self):
                  ...途中省略...
    if self.rect.colliderect(self.en1.rect):
                  ...以後省略...
```

そのため整数が代入された`self.en1`には`rect`というattributeは無いということでエラーになっているのでしょう。

---

正しいかどうかわかりませんが、その上の行で作成している`en1`をパラメータとして指定して試してみると良いかもしれません。

```
en1 = En1Sprite("to.PNG", (4400, 0), (-4,3), 0)

#### player = PlayerSprite("m.png", 0, 600, 0, 5, 0) #### 元の行
player = PlayerSprite("m.png", en1, 600, 0, 5, 0) #### 新しい行 0 を en1 に変更
```

しかし、その直前の2重の`for`ループの中で多数の`En1Sprite`のオブジェクトを同じ名前の`en1`という変数に代入する処理を行っており、この処理との関係が不明なため、何が起こるか？ あるいはループの外で`en1`に再度オブジェクトが代入されることなどにより、意図したことが発生しないといった別の現象が発生する可能性も考えられます。

```
    #sprite
    s = -10
for m in range(7):
    m = random.randint(0, 800)
    for n in range(300):
     n = random.randint(200, 1000000)
     en1 = En1Sprite("to.PNG", (n, m), (s, 3), 0)
```